# How is it that a file compression program can use up more RAM than the uncompressed file it is compressing?

Tags: compression

I was compressing a 120 MB set of files on the best compression that 7z offers and noticed that it was consuming nearly 600MB of RAM at peak.

Why do these compression programs use so much RAM even when working with realitivly small data sets, even to the point of consuming multiple times more memory than the uncompressed size of its data set?

Just curious, I'm more interested in the technical side of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never been into compression technically, but lets start searching ...

The 7z helpfile mentions:

> **LZMA** is an algorithm based on
>   Lempel-Ziv algorithm. It provides very
>   fast decompression (about 10-20 times
>   faster than compression). Memory
>   requirements for compression and
>   decompression also are different (see
>   d={Size}[b|k|m] switch for details).

(Note that the L-Z algorithm article on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch) does *not* mention anything about memory requirement.)

> d={Size}[b|k|m]  Sets **Dictionary size
>   for LZMA**. You must specify the size in
>   bytes, kilobytes, or megabytes. The
>   maximum value for dictionary size is 1
>   GB = 2^30 bytes. Default values for
>   LZMA are 24 (16 MB) in normal mode, 25
>   (32 MB) in maximum mode (-mx=7) and 26
>   (64 MB) in ultra mode (-mx=9). If you
>   do not specify any symbol from the set
>   [b|k|m], the dictionary size will be
>   calculated as DictionarySize = 2^Size
>   bytes. For decompressing a file
>   compressed by LZMA method with
>   dictionary size N, you need about N
>   bytes of memory (RAM) available.

Following wikipedia further to the article about [dictionary coders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_coder) it would appear that the algorithm works by comparing the data to be compressed to a set of data in a "dictionary" that has to be based on the raw data that is to be compressed.

Regardless of how this dictionary is built, since it must be kept in memory, the RAM requirement is a function of this dictionary. And since this dictionary isn't raw data, but some uncompressed data structure, it will (can) be bigger than the raw data that is processed. *Makes sense?*

Comment: Read this, it can give you some clues: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77_and_LZ78

Answer (score 4):

If the other answer is too challenging for someone to read because it has a lot of technical jargon, I offer my answer.

A file is stored in the hard drive or solid drive. What is a file you ask? I answer, a bunch of 1s and 0s arranged in a particular order that it looks like a file from the outside. What is an executable program `*.exe`? It is machine code executable, also a bunch of 1s and 0s. It is also stored in your disk drive. When you click on the file compression executable, the code instructions algorithm gets loaded from the `*.exe` in the disk drive into the RAM. Only then it is able to run. The computer's CPU runs programs and reads/writes data. It cannot get anything directly from the disk drive. It has to load everything into the RAM memory first, which acts as a middle man between the CPU and the disk drive where all your data is stored.

Now the file compression program is being run by the CPU in the RAM. What do the code instructions tell the CPU to do? They tell it to load the actual file itself from the disk drive into the RAM memory so that the program can work with it. So now we have two things in the RAM memory: the program itself, and the file.

You tell this file compression program to compress the file. However it cannot magically just do that. To be compressed, a file has to be arranged in a certain order, as tightly as possible. Perhaps prior to compression, the file was somewhat unorganized, like your file cabinet. The file compression program has to organize the file as neatly and tightly as possible. To do this it has to temporarily put the file into an even more unorganized state in order to find all the pieces where everything belongs.

Think about how you would compress your papers. You would first spread them all over your desk to that you can see all them, and them order them by categories, and start putting the papers into folders.

So now we have three things in the RAM memory:
1. The program instructions itself.
2. The original file which was loaded from the disk drive.
3. A temporary copy of the original file, which is in state of being taken apart and put back together.
Maybe multiple temporary copies of the whole file or even parts of it are made in the RAM to make it easier for the program to organize and compress this file. Do you now see how file compression programs can take up much more RAM when they are working compared relatively to the size of the original file in the disk drive?

The amount of RAM used up during this process depends on the skill of the programmer who designed the application. There are clever and efficient ways to write the code so that it minimizes the consumption of RAM. And then there are brute force ways to achieve the same task but it runs slower and takes up more RAM. RAM may even be wasted if the program has a memory leak. Think of a memory leak as making multiple copies of the same data but then leaving it on the desk and never even bothering to clean up after yourself.

Eventually though all the temporary copies would be condensed into the compressed version of the file. It's still in the RAM memory though, so then that compressed version of the file has to be sent all the way back to the hard drive disk where it is saved permanently.

The main idea is that to reach a state of low entropy you should temporarily go through a state of high entropy. This is of course written in the most general terms.

[image: Picture of the RAM inside]